# PHP Error when loading php_gd2.dll

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to gd2 for images but I am unable to call the methods since I am having troubles loading the php_gd2.dll. I am using Windows 10 and I have tried reinstalling PHP and Apache several times now.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\\php_gd2.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: What is the content of line starting with `extension_dir` in your php.ini?

Comment: extension_dir = "ext"

Comment: I'm not really sure about this, but you can try put there an absolute address of that folder: `C:/something/PHP/ext`.

Comment: Surprisingly this works. Thanks!

Comment: I'll make an answer from that, if it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your parameter `extension_dir` in php.ini by an absolute address to extensions directory. Something like `C:/path_to_PHP/ext`.